# C++ и system('pause")

Tags: c++

Не работает system("pause"), пока не подключу iostream.h
Как это связанно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тем, что эта ф-я описывается в <stdlib.h>, а iostream.h подключает этот хидер